# remove HTML from string via regex

Tags: regex

how do get remove the html completely and get the remaining text

```
'Abdulsalami</title><style>.ag8o{position:absolute;clip:rect(434px,auto,auto,434px);}</style><div class=ag8o>Spending time doing you <a href=http://arr'
```

i want to get `'Abdulsalami'`

what would be the regex to do that ?

Comment: Is there a good reason you want to try a regex? (There are tons of good reasons not to.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: The input string is not well formed, the tag at the end is "corrupt". I do not understand why you want to ignore <div> tag text? Style tag should be ignored, but ... you just should explain what your requirements are. Do you just want to extract text before the first tag? Or the text before </title> tag? Please provide also the language you code in.

Comment: sql injection on my database , all rows  and columns have data like this , each columns has different ending  but the it always starts with </title> so i need to find and replace all sql injected text , i will use regex  on sql file  which has insert statements

Answer (score 0):

A single RegEx can't match all the variations of HTML.

Try using Jsoup.

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

or Jericho Html parser (you can download it from here - http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html)

```
Source htmlSource = new Source(htmlText);
Segment htmlSeg = new Segment(htmlSource, 0, htmlSource.length());
Renderer htmlRend = new Renderer(htmlSeg);
System.out.println(htmlRend.toString());
```